# Android sync without content provider

Tags: android

I use a service to check for stuff on the server, and wanted to transition that to use the standard android sync capability.  However, the config file confuses me.

android:contentAuthority
android:accountType
android:supportsUploading

I don't know what these represent and don't have any meaningful values for them.  It seems like I'll need a content provider to use the sync, but that's not how I implemented everything.

Any good links or info on implementing sync with your own code?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement anything you want for your sync needs.  Android sync adapter provides a framework for sync'ing which includes states, callbacks, settings, scheduled events, etc.  You can use what you need and leave the rest for other apps.  There are helper functions that makes it easy to use consistently with the syncing that you find in Accounts & Sync Settings.

The android:contentAuthority is the unique identifier used during the broadcast that your sync adapter would respond to.  It is like "com.mycompany.myproject. ...".  The flag android:supportsUploading is required for permission to send data out of your application.  I believe it is coordinated with some android:uses-permission setting.

I don't think you are *required* to have a CP, but quite often you would and if you do, it can be really thin to be the authority.